# IdSMTP stuck on the Connect method

Tags: c++, delphi, smtp, indy, smtpclient

I am using IdSMTP and creating / destroying the TIdSMTP component dynamically in my form.  Most of the time there are no issues with the smtp.Connect but I found that there are situations where the main UI will get stuck and become unresponsive.

I added the ConnectTimeout and the ReadTimeout properties but still getting the same issue.  The application becomes unresponsive and forces us to kill the process.

```
  smtp.ConnectTimeout := 10000;
  smtp.ReadTimeout := 10000;
  smtp.Connect;
  if smtp.Connected then
  begin
    smtp.Send(Mess);
    smtp.Disconnect;
  end
```

I have a OnStatus event bound to stmp that is being raised by idstmp control 
Resolving
Connecting 
Connected

But for some reason the Connect still makes the application free and act unresponsive.

Comment: whenever I use TidSMTP, I use it inside a thread, in this way, the UI will be responsive at all time, use callbacks|events to show progress/messages/etc.

Comment: The underlying issue is that the component is blocked / stuck on the Connect method... if I set both ConnectTimeout and ReadTimeout.  Simply moving this into a thread will just mean UI is not stuck but Thread will still be blocked doing the send unless I make a different timeout on it.

Comment: The `ConnectTimeout` only applies when the socket is actually connecting to the server, and the `ReadTimeout` only applies when reading data after the connection is established. Before either of those can occur, `TIdSMTP` has to perform a DNS lookup of the specified `Host` if it is not already an IP address, and that DNS lookup is performed by the OS outside of Indy's control. If your machine's DNS settings are not setup correctly, that can cause this type of deadlock in `Connect()`. You can verify that if the `OnStatus` event reaches `hsResolving` but does not reach `hsConnecting`.

Comment: Ok I will add the status information in logging to observe where it's getting "stuck".  However is there a way to set resolvetimeout for dns?  Or do I have to write my own code to resolve dns with timeout?

Comment: As I said, the OS is the one performing the actual DNS lookup, not Indy. The OS decides when it wants to give up, not Indy. So no, there is no way to set a timeout on DNS lookups that Indy uses internallly, if in fact that is where the deadlock is actually occuring. You could try using the `TIdDNSResolver` component for your own DNS queries, which has a `WaitingTime` property (but that is currently only used for UDP-based queries, which are used if you are not requesting AXFR or IXFR records, which use TCP-based queries instead).

Comment: Do you recommend that I should use TIdDNSResolver to get ip address from hostname and it should solve the issue with resolving the ip  and hangup in smtp ?

Comment: So after adding more logging on the status of the IdSMTP I saw Resolving, Connecting, and COnnected.  But any other logging I had after smtp.Connect; were not logged.  Is there any other part which can make the connect method not exit properly?